# Property 'map' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning a react course online. When I try to display the list of items from an array using map to display in a child component , I keep getting "cannot read property map of undefined.

Error is thrown while fetching data from `users`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


let userList = [
  { name: "John", age: 24, place: "India" },
  { name: "Henry", age: 24, place: "India" },
  { name: "Ulrich", age: 24, place: "India" }
];

const AppChild = ({ name, age, place, Graduated }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <p>name: {name}</p>
      <p>age: {age}</p>
      <p>place: {place}</p>
      {/* access the value via props */}
      <p>Graduated: {Graduated ? "yes!" : "no!"}</p>
    </section>
  );
};


export default class App extends Component {
    
  state = {
    userExists: true,
    isGraduated: true,
    loading: true,
  }; 


  toggleStatus = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      userExists: !prevState.userExists // value : false
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { users } = this.props; 
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <h4>
          Profile Status is {this.state.userExists ? "Updated" : "Outdated"}
          <br />
          <button onClick={this.toggleStatus}>Check Status</button>
        </h4>
        {users.map(user => (
          
          <AppChild
            name={user.name}
            age={user.age}
            place={user.place}
            Graduated={this.state.isGraduated} // passing state to child component
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App users={userList} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: The error tells you that `this.props.users` is undefined. Which means that `userList` is undefined. Where do you declare and initialize this variable?

Comment: `let userList = [
  { name: "John", age: 24, place: "India" },
  { name: "Henry", age: 24, place: "India" },
  { name: "Ulrich", age: 24, place: "India" }
];`

Comment: i added this before class definition

Comment: can you add the full code showing where userList is declared or imported

Comment: The code you posted works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/a4qbuvk2/

Comment: The above code with static predefined `userList` works just fine

Comment: I believe the problem is that you render `<App />` somewhere else, without the user list prop. The clue is in the `export default class App` – this file is both using the `App` class and exporting it for something else. Check the index.js file, it probably has a `ReactDOM.render(<App />)` line.

Comment: I can replicate the error here: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-sea-0w20u?file=/src/App.js – note how also index.js tries to render the App class.

Comment: If you are getting data from a server,post the api request code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the correct code. In the previous code I was trying to render `<App/>` in both index.js and App.js. Thanks everyone for helping me out

=>index.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./App"

let userList = [
    { name: "John", age: 24, place: "India" },
    { name: "Henry", age: 24, place: "India" },
    { name: "Ulrich", age: 24, place: "India" }
  ];

  
ReactDOM.render(<App users={userList} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

=> App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// child component
const AppChild = ({ name, age, place, Graduated }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <p>name: {name}</p>
      <p>age: {age}</p>
      <p>place: {place}</p>
      {/* access the value via props */}
      <p>Graduated: {Graduated ? "yes!" : "no!"}</p>
    </section>
  );
};

// parent component
export default class App extends Component {
    
  state = {
    userExists: true,
    isGraduated: true,
    loading: true,
  }; 

  toggleStatus = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      userExists: !prevState.userExists // value : false
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { users } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <h4>
          Profile Status is {this.state.userExists ? "Updated" : "Outdated"}
          <br />
          <button onClick={this.toggleStatus}>Check Status</button>
        </h4>
         {users.map((user) => {
          return(
            <AppChild
              name={user.name}
              age={user.age}
              place={user.place}
              Graduated={this.state.isGraduated} // passing state to child component
            />
          )})}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a return in the statement`{users.map(user => return (....`

Comment: But I don't think we need a return statement there.

Comment: Don't forget to add curly braces when you use return statement. So your code would be like.
`{users.map((user) => {return (<YourComponent />))}`

Comment: I am sure it's a quick fix. Can you make a sandbox example. So it would be easy to resolve

Comment: @AliWahab: Well I fixed the error with the above code.

Comment: @AliWahab It was just fine before. You don't need the curly braces and return statement for one-line arrow functions.

Comment: Hey I know it can work without that. But sometimes it may cause problems because of long JSX

Comment: It can, but in this case it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out the problem, we follow the bouncing ball. From the error message, I guess that the problem occurs on the line

```
        {users.map(user => (
```

(You can confirm this from the stack trace given with the error message.)

The error tells you that `users` is undefined. So we look at the declaration for `users`:

```
    const { users } = this.props;
```

Ok, so it is really `this.props.users`. So we look where this is passed in:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App users={userList} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here you are passing the value of `userList` to a prop named `users`. However, in the code you show here, there is no variable named `userList`. This is as far as we can go with the information you have given. You need to find where this variable is declared and initialized to continue solving the problem.

Comment: I tried `console.log(users)` and the output is showing in the console. So the list is not empty.

Comment: `undefined` is not the same as an empty list. I tried to run your updated code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a4qbuvk2/) and do not get the error you ask about. Please update your question with code that actually causes the error.

Comment: Buddy! I tried running this code several times. I keep getting this error. Let me try once again

Comment: @AkhilSuseelan The code you are running is different than the code you posted here. Copy and paste the exact code you are running.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to log **users** after following line of code

```
const { users } = this.props;
```

you'll see **users** is undefined.

Error message "cannot read property map of undefined" says the same thing, you can not apply **map** helper on an undefined variable. The **map** works with arrays